# Declare a typescript module that is both a type and a value

Tags: javascript, wordpress, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm making typings for the WordPress `wp.customize` API. However, I've hit a snag and don't know, how to declare the top-level export.

The problem is following:

- `wp.customize` extends a class called `Values`, that is defined in the "module". On top of that, this class has a call signature (because it really isn't a typescript class but a myriad of horrible JS hacks). So you need to be able to call `wp.customize()`
- `wp.customize` has member variables and functions. So these need to be accessible, e.g. `wp.customize.get()`
- `wp.customize` also contains classes & types such as `Setting`, so you nned to be able to do

```
function xxx (a: wp.customize.Setting){
```

I don't know how to do these all at the same time. I am not the author of the library, so I can in no way change it, I just want to create typings for it. What I did is:

```
// index.d.ts

import {Customize} from './Customize';

declare const customize: Customize;

export = customize;



// Customize.d.ts

export interface Customize extends Values {
    Setting: typeof Setting;
    get(): any;
}
```

I would ideally like to import the typings in the same way other WordPress typings are implemented, but this is not strictly necessary:

```
declare const wp: {
  customize: typeof import("wordpress__customize");
};
```

However, then I can't use the types, such as `wp.customize.Setting`. I get `error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'wp'.`